# jQuery contents don't fadeIn during .load() success

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, load

I've poked around through several similar issues, but none seem to have worked.  I am trying to use a jQuery click event to fadeOut() a target div, asynchronously load() the target div's content from the clicked element's href, and then fadeIn() the new content.

The site in question is http://clients.weareno1.com/worklocal.org/.

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pri_nav a").click(function() {
        $("#content").fadeOut(400, "linear").load(this.href, function() {
            $("#content").fadeIn(800, "linear");
        });
    });
});
```

Setting passing 'e' to the click function (i.e. `$("#pri_nav a").click(function(e) {e.preventDefault(); [....]` gets me most of the way there, but then I'm left to manually strip and replace the "selected" class from the anchor's parent li.  Worst case, that's what I'll do, but it seems a little unnecessarily complicated.

Any input would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine to me (Chrome 9), aside from the jumpy scrollbars.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented the dynamic replacement of the "selected" class on the anchors in question, so that part is now working smoothly.  The consequence is that even though the e.preventDefault() is now allowing the fade animation to work the way I intended, it is now preventing the address bar from reflecting the appropriate page.  So now, the trick is, how do I get an elegant animation, but still display the appropriate URL in the address bar / regain any SEO benefits I might have lost with the preventDefault() function.

Comment: I just removed the e.preventDefault() function so you can see the address bar location correctly update and the load request snap into place.

Comment: ...and by "load request snap into place" I mean "not work correctly".

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your comments about SEO gains. Search engines don't execute JavaScript code. As long as your application works with JavaScript turned off, search engines (and people with accessibility needs) will be able to follow links.

The `fade*` methods are not synchronous. I wouldn't chain load like that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pri_nav a").click(function() {
        var a = this;
        $("#content").fadeOut(400, "linear", function() {
            $("#content").load(a.href, function() {
                $("#content").fadeIn(800, "linear");
            });
        });
        return false;  // or prevent default
    });
});
```